# Haskell: A recursive type implementation: RGB, color inversion, color mixing

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have this recursive, algebraic data type for representing colors and mixing/inverting particular RGB channels:

```
data Color = Red | Green | Blue | Mix Color Color | Invert Color
  deriving Show

rgb :: Color -> [Double]
rgb Red = [1,0,0]
rgb Green = [0,1,0]
rgb Blue = [0,0,1]

rgb (Invert Red) = let cols = rgb Red
                   in [1 - cols !! 0, cols !! 1, cols !! 2]
                   
rgb (Invert Green) = let cols = rgb Red
                     in [cols !! 0, 1 - cols !! 1, cols !! 2]
                   
rgb (Invert Blue) = let cols = rgb Red
                    in [cols !! 0, cols !! 1, 1 - cols !! 2]
                   
rgb (Invert color) = rgb color

rgb (Mix Red Green) = let cols1 = rgb Red
                          cols2 = rgb Green
                          cols3 = rgb Blue
                          ave = (cols1 !! 0 + cols2 !! 1) / 2
                      in [ave, ave, cols3 !! 2]

rgb (Mix Green Red) = rgb (Mix Red Green)

rgb (Mix Green Blue) = let cols1 = rgb Red
                           cols2 = rgb Green
                           cols3 = rgb Blue
                           ave = (cols1 !! 0 + cols2 !! 1) / 2
                       in [ave, ave, cols3 !! 2]

rgb (Mix Blue Green) = rgb (Mix Green Blue)

rgb (Mix Red Blue) = let cols1 = rgb Red
                         cols2 = rgb Green
                         cols3 = rgb Blue
                         ave = (cols1 !! 0 + cols2 !! 1) / 2
                      in [ave, ave, cols3 !! 2]

rgb (Mix Blue Red) = rgb (Mix Red Blue)
```

When I run the code in

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  print (rgb (Mix Red Green))
  print (rgb (Mix Red Green))
  print (rgb (Mix Red (Mix Red Green)))
  print (rgb (Invert Red))
  print (rgb (Invert (Mix Red (Mix Red Green))))
  print (rgb (Mix (Invert Red) (Invert Green)))
```

I get the runtime exception:

```
[1.0,1.0,1.0]
[1.0,1.0,1.0]
*** Exception: Main.hs:(158,1)-(195,39): Non-exhaustive patterns in function rgb
```

What am I doing wrong here?

(I just started with Haskell algebraic datatypes, so, of course, I make mistakes.)

Comment: BTW the implementation for `rgb (Invert color)` is also wrong, not in a way that will crash but it just doesn't invert the color.

Comment: Not just for the variable `color` case, but all the `Invert` implementations are wrong.

Comment: This looks like a fun project. Aside from your problems with recursion, I think you might also not have the API quite right, either: it's impossible to derive `[1,1,1]` or `[0,0,0]` with these primitives and combinators: any amount of mixing will just stay medium-grey. You may need to include black as a primitive, or add a combinator that doesn't average, such as `Max`.

Comment: @amalloy actually not true: black is the limit of a tree-balanced folding of `Mix` over `cycle [Red, Green, Blue]`, white is the limit of folding over the inverted version.

Comment: ...well, not really black and white, only `[1/3,1/3,1/3]` dark-grey and `[2/3,2/3,2/3]` light-grey. This could be changed by applying a nonlinear function after each `Mix`. But the limits of 0 and 1 are kind of arbitrary anyway.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Like I said, medium-grey. The limits of 1 and 0 are arbitrary, but it's not arbitrary to ask for mixed colors that are as bright as the pure colors. If you change the "arbitrary" 1s to 2/3s everywhere, e.g. define `red = [2/3,0,0]`, then the same complaint holds: now you can't get a pure `[2/3,2/3,2/3]` anymore.

Comment: @amalloy the mixed colour rgb(1,1,1) is not "as bright as" e.g. the pure colour rgb(0,0,1), it's actually much brighter. Computer displays happen to be designed in such a way that the limits of rgb components and their combinations coincide, but there are many applications where this isn't the case at all. Tunable lasers, filament-mixing 3D printers, etc. etc..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `Mix`, you only pattern match on `Mix Red Green`, `Mix Blue Red`, etc. Not on `Mix (Invert Red) Green`, etc. or `Mix (Mix Red Green) Red`. Making patterns for all these is impossible, since your data structure can produce an infinite amount of values. Indeed, for example `rgb (Invert (Invert (… (Invert Red) …)))` with an arbitrary number of `Invert`s.

You can pick the value(s) wrapped  in `Invert` or `Mix` and then call `rgb` on these and invert or mix the end product, like:

```
rgb :: Color -> [Double]
rgb Red = [1, 0, 0]
rgb Green = [0, 1, 0]
rgb Blue = [0, 0, 1]
rgb (Invert x) = map (1 -) (rgb x)
rgb (Mix x1 x2) = zipWith mid (rgb x1) (rgb x2)
  where
    mid y1 y2 = (y1 + y2) / 2
```

For the sample data, this then produces:

```
ghci> rgb (Mix Red Green)
[0.5,0.5,0.0]
ghci> rgb (Mix Red Green)
[0.5,0.5,0.0]
ghci> rgb (Mix Red (Mix Red Green))
[0.75,0.25,0.0]
ghci> rgb (Invert Red)
[0.0,1.0,1.0]
ghci> rgb (Invert (Mix Red (Mix Red Green)))
[0.25,0.75,1.0]
ghci> rgb (Mix (Invert Red) (Invert Green))
[0.5,0.5,1.0]
```